# List all procedures along with the tables and columns used in that procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, data-dictionary

Last night got a call from my team lead and he asked me to make the list of all the procedures along with the tables and columns used in Oracle.

I got a query to list all the procedures along with tables and dblink but couldn't get column names (along with DML if possible) used in that Procedure :

```
select DISTINCT OWNER, NAME, referenced_name, referenced_link_name, referenced_type 
from dba_dependencies 
where OWNER = 'OWNER_NAME';
```

My required output is as follows:

- Owner_Name
- Procedure_Name
- Referenced_name
- Referenced_link
- Referenced_type
- Column_Name,
- dml_type(select/insert/update).

Please help if possible..

Answer (score 0):

columns will be in `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.

as for the SQL statements, this is a bit more difficult, but doable if you have Diagnostics pack licensed; here's the outline (works in 11g or above):

`DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY.top_level_sql_id` is the SQL id of the calling procedure,

so listing `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY.sql_id` for that top_level_sql_id is "all" the SQL from the execution of the procedure.

`DBA_HIST_SQL_TEXT` can be queried to get the sql text for the sql_id.

If you don't have the Diagnostics Pack, you'd have to instrument v$session for the top_level_sql_id's and sql_id's and the look in v$sql for the text.

Comment: select distinct sql_id from DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY where top_level_sql_id = :top_level_sql_id;

Comment: select sql_text from dba_hist_sql_text where sql_id = :sql_id;

Comment: select column_name from dba_tab_columns where owner= :owner and table_name = :table_name;

Comment: the rest needs to be tweaked as per  you requirments.